# How to publish result from result of two threads whichever gets result earlier?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two classes: `TNsyncer.java` and `DNSClient.java` .
Both give the same result, but the method used to get the result is different

Now I have a class, `Main.java`.

I want to populate the result by calling both the class in two different threads from `Main.java` and publish the result on the basis :

- if any thread gets the result first, this will give me the result and if one fails (`Exception`) then wait for second one
- if both fail then publish the final exception state

Both classes throw Exception.

I am doing something like this:

```
Object o =new Object();

Thread searchThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
          info = new DNSClient(getApplicationContext()).checkDNSAnswer(nameSearch.getText().toString());
          catch (final Exception ex) { Post some result;}

     Thread searchThread2 =new Thread(new Runnable() {  
         @Override
         public void run() {
             new TnSyncer().getInstance().sync(nameSearch.getText().toString(),CallerId.getInstance().getPreferences().getCountryCode()) ;
             catch (final Exception ex) { Post some result;}

           Thread third = new Thread(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   synchronized(o1){
                       try {
                           wait();
                       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                   }
               }
           });
```

I have put my code and need to wait on an object, but problem is that if I wait on the same object, then both threads will not run simultaneously

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, you have not posted any code or the exception

Comment: The OP does not need to post "the exception" because this is not a request to debug some existing code, it is a request for how to do something.

Answer (score 1):

You can model `TNSyncer` and `DNSClient` as implementations of the `java.util.concurrent.Callable` interface. `Callables` can be submitted to an `Executor`, and you can wait for their results using a `java.util.concurrent.Future`.

If you want to wait for any result, you can use an implementation of the `java.util.concurrent.CompletionService`.

Example:

```
class Result {
}

class TnSyncer implements Callable<Result> {
    @Override
    public Result call() throws Exception {
        // TODO: implement
    }
}

class DnsClient implements Callable<Result> {
    // [...]
}

static Executor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(6);

public static Result lookup(String host) {
    ExecutorCompletionService<Result> service = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executor);
    service.submit(new TnSyncer(host));
    service.submit(new DnsClient(host));
    return service.take().get();
}
```

There are multiple implementations of `Executor` and you should have a look at them, determine how big you want the thread pool to be, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help.but what happens in the case of exception.Does it also post the exception case. Although I need to print the same exception in both the cases

Comment: The method `Future.get()` (which you invoke in the last line - `service.take().get()`) throws a `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException` if your callable threw an exception. You can call `getCause()` on it to get the original exception back.

Comment: If the first one throws an exception, you can call `take()` again to wait for the output from the second one.

Comment: Ok thanks.I will implement using same scenario you just told.
So service.submit will call new thread for both class.right?

Comment: Each submit will take a thread from the thread pool and run your code on it. After running, the thread is returned to the thread pool to be used again later. You can share the thread pool for other uses - if you call the Executor directly using `Executor.execute(Runnable)` you an use it for other purposes too, whenever you would otherwise create a new Thread before.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find which one is faster. It would be easier to just time them both and print the method with the better time. Otherwise you might want to look into something like coroutine, or some way to manage your threads better. I think the first way would suit what you are trying to do much better.

Answer (score 0):

You might try an approach that uses task and response queues to communicate with your "services" that are running in separate threads.  The following tactics shows this method:

- Make TNSyncher and DNSClient, each implementing interface Runnable; create and start each one with an input and an output queue.
- In each client check on the "task" queue, and wait (sleep a short while) if nothing there
- In your main add your requested task to each queue
- In your main issue waits and check each response queue; handling your first winner move on, if exception wait for second win or exception.

(In each of your separately threaded tasks you might improve things by having them check for an abort signal or a stop and exit signal .. and use the former if you get a winner, and the latter when you want to stop those threads)